# Not able to include standard c++ library headers in vs code esp-idf extension

Tags: c++, c, esp-idf

I am not able to include some standard libraries:

```
#include <stdio.h> // <= this works
// #include <thread> // <= error: "No such file or directory"
// #include <algorithm> // <= error: "No such file or directory"

void app_main(void)
{

}
```

The error is generated by compiler `xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc.exe`. There is no error from C/C++ Intellisense. And I am able to find the necessary header by pressing F12. They are placed on the path `C:\Espressif\tools\xtensa-esp32-elf\esp-2021r2-patch3-8.4.0\xtensa-esp32-elf\xtensa-esp32-elf\include\c++\8.4.0`. There is no such path in the compiler `-I` arguments.

How can I deal with this error?

Answer (score 0):

Thread and algorithm are both part of C++ standard library, not C standard library. I've renamed the source file to .cpp (CMakeLists.txt was updated by VSCode automatically). Then I added:

```
extern "C" {
   void app_main();
}
```

And it works. Hope it helps somebody.